# Quick Program help (quick fix)

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods

I have a homework assignment where I need to make an array of lightbulb objects. Then add a method to "turn them on". I need to have a nested loop to have an imaginary person turn on every bulb then pull the string on every other bulb then every 3rd and so on until its every 20 bulbs. This is the code I have. It compiles but when I run it, it just goes forever. PLEASE HELP

```
   public class LightBulb
   {
      public boolean isTurnedOn; 

       public LightBulb()
      {
         isTurnedOn = false;
      }


       public boolean isOn()
      {
      if(isTurnedOn==false)
         return false;  
      return true; 
      }


       public void pullString()
      {
       if(isTurnedOn==true){
         isTurnedOn=false;
       }
       isTurnedOn=true;

      }

   }



public class LightDriver
{

    public static void main(String[]arg)
    {
        int numOn=0;
        LightBulb[]Bulb=new LightBulb[100];
        for(int a=0;a<100;a++){
            Bulb[a]=new LightBulb();
        }
        for(int b=0;b<=19;b++){
            for(int c=0;c<=100;c=b+1){
                Bulb[c].pullString();
            }
        }
        for(int d=0;d<100;d++){
            if(Bulb[d].isTurnedOn==true){
                numOn++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(numOn+" lightbulbs are on");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is causing the problem:

```
for(int b=0;b<=19;b++){
    for(int c=0;c<=100;c=b+1){
        Bulb[c].pullString();
    }
}
```

For every iteration of the inner `for` loop, you are setting `c = b + 1` which means that `c` is not changing, since `b` is not changing.

I think what you want is this:

```
for(int b=1; b <= 20; b++){
    for(int c=0; c < 100; c = c + b){
        Bulb[c].pullString();
    }
}
```

Also, your pullString method sets isTurnedOn to true no matter what it originally was. I think this is what you want instead:

```
public void pullString()
{
    if (isTurnedOn)
    {
        isTurnedOn = false;
    }
    else
    {
        isTurnedOn = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it still runs forever. That was definitely a problem but there is still another one lurking apparently.

Comment: It doesn't look like anything is wrong... Maybe post the `pullString()` method?

Comment: Wait, I don't see it. I edited the question at about the same time as you did, and I might have accidentally edited it out.

Comment: it should be there now. I really appreciate your help

Comment: It should not be running forever. I changed `c <= 100` to `c < 100` or there will be an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Two things I wanted to verify: In your `pullString()` method, you are setting `isTurnedOn` to true regardless of what it originally was. Did you intend to do this? Also, you never call the `isOn()` method. Do you have any reason to keep it?

Comment: I guess  I dont need that method. IDK why but mine still complies but then nothing happens when it runs

Comment: Is it still running, or does it not print? When I ran it, it did print "100 light bulbs are on"

Comment: it runs until I end it and does not print anything

Comment: You did change your for loop, right? And it is not showing an error of any kind?

Comment: I changed it to exactly what you said. is there anywhere you can post what you have somewhere?

Comment: i got it to say 100 bulbs are on but I dont think 100 should be the right number. after they are all turned on when it goes through again when a string is pulled it should turn off the bulb. Do you see anything that is wrong with the pullstring or something?

Comment: I told you earlier, your pullString() method sets isTurned on to true, regardless of what it was before. I think I know what you want instead: see my edited answer.

Comment: If you liked my answer, please accept it by clicking the check mark to the left. I would really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this loop

```
  for(int b=0;b<=19;b++){
     for(int c=0;c<=100;c=b+1){
        Bulb[c].pullString();
     }
  }
```

your value of c never increases, as it is always set to `b+1` which - within a single iteration of the b loop - never changes. As such, you never reach the termination condition of the loop. Here is a fix

```
  for(int b=0;b<=19;b++){
     int c = b+1; //assign initial value outside of inner loop
     for(;c<=100;c++){ //increment value inside of inner loop
        Bulb[c].pullString();
     }
  }
```